# Erroneous case/rep labeling in MATLAB FDA plot_fit plot titles

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm using [Jim Ramsay's FDA package for MATLAB](http://functionaldata.org) to do functional analysis on data I've acquired through an experiment. I am setting up the labels for my functional data object, generating it, and plotting it with the following code:

```
% Set up labels

fdnames = cell(1,3);
fdnames{1} = 'Time (ms)';
cnd = cell(1,2);
cnd{1} = 'Condition';
cnd{2} = ['C1'; 'C2'; 'C3'];
fdnames{2} = cnd;
fdnames{3} = 'Values';

% Generate functional data object from
% arguments (t), data (y), basis object (bss),
% default value for derivative order (4), lambda (0.1),
% and labels (fdnames)

fdObj = data2fd(t, y, bss, 4, 0.1, fdnames);

% Plot

plot_fit(y, t, fdObj);
```

This produces 3 plots. All three of them have 'C1' in their label, as opposed to 'C1', 'C2', and 'C3', which are the labels I gave to the cases/replications in my functional object.

[image]

I would like to plot my functional object with the correct labels appearing on the plots. Any help from more experienced MATLAB and FDA users is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the `plot_fit` function from the FDA package. Here is part of the code for that function:

```
% ...
casenames = fdnames{2};
% ...
%  plot the results
if residual
  %  plot the residuals
  ylimit = [min(min(min(res))), max(max(max(res)))];
    for i = 1:nrep 
        for j = 1:nvar
            % ...
            if nrep > 1
                if iscell(casenames)
                    title(['\fontsize{12} ', casenames{2}(j,:), ...
                        '  RMS residual = ',num2str(sqrt(MSE(j,i)))])
                else
                    title(['\fontsize{12} Case ', num2str(i), ...
                        '  RMS residual = ',num2str(sqrt(MSE(j,i)))])
                end
            else
               % ...
            end
        end
        pause
   end
 else
  %  plot the data and fit
  % ...
    for i = 1:nrep 
        for j = 1:nvar
          % ...
            if nrep > 1
                if iscell(casenames)
                    title(['\fontsize{12} ', casenames{2}(j,:), ...
                        '  RMS residual = ',num2str(sqrt(MSE(j,i)))])
                else
                    title(['\fontsize{12} Case ', num2str(i), ...
                        '  RMS residual = ',num2str(sqrt(MSE(j,i)))])
                end
              % ...
```

Here, while the variables `i` and `j` iterate over the cases/reps and variables respectively, the line

```
title(['\fontsize{12} ', casenames{2}(j,:), ...
```

uses `j` as an argument to select which case/rep name will appear in the title. Updating the package to replace this line with

```
title(['\fontsize{12} ', casenames{2}(i,:), ...
```

may solve the problem.

Comment: I have contacted the developer of the FDA package, who confirmed this bug and this solution. Hence, I am accepting this answer.